# Are there any open datasets of board games that allow commercial usage?

Tags: data-request, games

I'd like to start working on a web application that relates to board games and eventually off of it. I'd like to know if there are any data sets out there that will fit this scenario.

I've found that BoardGameGeek has quite a large database with an [XML api](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/BGG_XML_API&redirectedfrom=XML_API#), unfortunately their [terms of service](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/XML_API_Terms_of_Use) restrict commercial usage.

Comment: What kind of data do you want? Discussions about board games? Point rankings of board games competitions? Names and descriptions of cards/items? Just a list of game names?

Comment: A bare minimum would be a list of games and editions of the games. I'd like to get descriptions and other information about them but I might be able to use another product api for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what type (and the structure) of the metadata you're looking for, have you thought of tapping a more general product API from the likes of Google, Amazon, eBay, etc.?

Also: consider contacting the API you found that has terms not to your liking. Perhaps you can create a special arrangement with them.

Answer (score 3):

The [Board & Card Games QA site](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) is full of open data about board games.

The whole content is licensed cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required.

Depending on what data you want, you might be interested in their tags too: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags

In particular, they have for each board game:

- a tag name
- a short description of the game

Comment: This might be a good starting point. The data available obviously isn't definitive but there is a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

not a strong board gamer, so i can't verify if these titles are "legit"...i recognize a few; a list of free alternatives to classic, well known games:
http://forum.dune2k.com/topic/26191-free-alternatives-to-classicwell-known-games/
the only game i looked @ was frozen bubbles, its 100% open source, as they are all advertised, denoted by the "This is Free Software" headline, seen here:
http://www.frozen-bubble.org/downloads/#framecontent

Comment: These look to be video games, I'm looking for board games.